# cURL error - SSL cert with Laravel + Mailgun

Tags: php, ssl, curl, laravel-5

I am using Mailgun + Mail class in laravel 5.2 in this sample code:

```
Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message)
                {

                    $message->from('hello@mywebsite.com', 'Marcos');

                    $message->to('amldesign@gmail.com');

                });
```

I've also handled exceptions by catching the $e Exceptions and laravel but it returns me this error:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))

I think that the services.php config is right:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN','mywebsite.com'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],
```

Any help in this regard to identify the issue will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you check that page which's error line give u ([curl.haxx.se](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)), you will see that line.

**CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.**

I'm not a laravel expert but i think something's wrong on your freamwork build. Did u made any SSL setting?